# Insert & Update with strong parameters for nested `belongs_to` association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form where a student can enroll in a class. When the user submits the form, he is enrolled in the class and his payment information is saved. In other words, an `Enrollment` object is created and the `Student` object is updated... except I cannot get the `Student` to update. Is this possible? If so, how?

My models...

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :enrollments
end

class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :student
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :student
end
```

My (abbreviated) form...

```
<%= form_for :enrollment, html: { id: "enrollment_form" } do |f| %>

    <%= f.fields_for :student_attributes do |student_builder| %>
        <%= student_builder.hidden_field :payment_name %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.hidden_field :payment_token %>

    <div class="field terms">
        <%= f.check_box :agreed_to_terms %>
        <%= f.label :agreed_to_terms, "I agree to the terms and conditions." %>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

My controller...

```
class EnrollmentsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @enrollment = Enrollment.new(enrollment_params)
    @enrollment.clazz_id = @clazz.id
    @enrollment.student_id = @student.id
    @enrollment.save
  end

  private
    def enrollment_params
      params.require(:enrollment).permit(:payment_token, :agreed_to_terms, student_attributes: [:payment_name])
    end
end
```

The POST parameters...

```
{
  "enrollment"=> {
    "student_attributes"=> {
      "payment_name"=> "MasterCard ending in 9840"
    },
    "payment_token"=> "CC11ho86XxVqsUW7Cn9YjCHg?1376007969212",
    "agreed_to_terms"=> "1"
  },
  "clazz_id"=> "7"
}
```

I've tried every permutation of `student`, `students`, `_attributes` in the form builder but none of them seem to work.

Comment: How are `@clazz` and `@student` created in your `create` action?

Comment: Try making the form be "fields_for :student" and then adding "attr_accessible :student_attributes" to the Enrollment class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, there are a few things I see:

1. Nested attributes, as described in [the API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html), "allow you to save attributes on associated records **through** the **parent**." This means that

   ```
   class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
       belongs_to :student
       accepts_nested_attributes_for :student
   end
   ```

   inherently won't work because you're trying to accept nested atributes **from** the parent. So you need to start by rethinking your Active Record assications.

   If we pretend that's all squared away, then more syntactical errors are:
2. Replace

   ```
   <%= f.fields_for :student_attributes do |student_builder| %>
   ```

   with

   ```
   <%= f.fields_for :students do |student_builder| %>
   ```

   This can be confusing, but passing `:students` to the `fields_for` helper calls the nested student object, whereas `:student_attributes` is the hash key from the POST parameters that `fields_for` produces.
3. In your strong parameters, you also need to permit the student `:id` so that your updating action has a reference. Otherwise, it will just create a new student. So change it to

   ```
   private
     def enrollment_params
       params.require(:enrollment).permit(:payment_token, :agreed_to_terms, student_attributes: [:payment_name, :id])
     end
   ```

I'm not sure if that's everything, but hopefully it's a start. Good luck.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure I understand the difference you're trying to make between `through` and `from`.

Comment: The `has_many` and `belongs_to` association methods establish a one-way relationship. With your current configuration, you can access a particular student's enrollments with `Student.find(foo).enrollments`. You **cannot** go the other way around (e.g. `Enrollment.find(foo).students`. So with this relationship, Student can `accepts_nested_attributes_for :enrollments`, but Enrollment cannot `accepts_nested_attributes_for :student`.

Comment: So you can either rework your form to accept everything through Student, or you can setup a [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association.